# options_from_collection_for_select how to use two variables as display values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a select tag like so:

```
= select_tag :cc, options_from_collection_for_select(@possible_contacts, "id", "email")
```

this lists each of `@possible_contacts` email addresses. each contact also has a name. what I would like to do is display each `@possible_contacts` as a name and email address like so:

```
Joe Smith <joe@gmail.com>
```

this requires both email and name...but I'm not sure how to put both of them in the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `options_for_select` instead, something like:

```
select_tag :cc, options_for_select(@possible_contacts.map{|contact| ["#{contact.name} <#{contact.email}>", contact.id])
```

For example, this is basically the same as:

```
select_tag :cc, options_for_select([['Joe Smith <joe@example.com>', 123], ['David H Hansson <dhh@example.com>', 987]])
```

which turns into:

```
<select id="cc" name="cc">
  <option value="123">Joe Smith &lt;joe@example.com&gt;</option>
  <option value="987">David H Hansson &lt;dhh@example.com&gt;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you forgotten the ending } after ]?